# Why does this VB.net code not send a email

Tags: vb.net, email

Why does my vb.net code not send an email. Please help. I hid my email and password. And yes I did have the correct email and password.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Mail.Subject = "Test"
    Mail.To.Add("*****@gmail.com")
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("*****@gmail.com")
    Mail.Body = "Test"
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com")
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*****@gmail.com", "*****")
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this,

go to your gmail account (www.gmail.com) login, and check that you have "enabled Pop for all mail". you can find this under the tab "Forwarding and POP/IMAP"

Comment: Does it just not send, or do you get an error?

Comment: I have just enabled it and I still get the same error. I forgot to say this but I am getting the error at the, "SMTP.Send(Mail)" part.

Comment: **WHAT** error are you getting?  You appear to have forgotten the single most important thing in your question....

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: @JonnyApple it my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just tried using my gmail account and it didn't work, however after doing this i was able to send an email via vb.net

sign out of your gmail account,
Sign back in and go to the following links.

1st - https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity
Fill out all your details.

2nd - switch this on
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps